# Partial View Result with script not properly executed through ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.net with MVC3. I am creating a page in which some part will be loaded dynamically depending on some selection and I am returning PartialView from Controller Action. Say the name of the partial view is MainView. In that partial view I am having one more partial view, the name of the partial view is specified from user selection namely SubView1 and SubView2. Based on the user selection I change the subviews(SubView1/SubView2).

In SubView1 I am having one Javascript function

```
function LoadLocationData(){
//Some code goes here
}
```

In SubView2 I am having one Javascript function

```
function LoadUserData(){
//Some code goes here
}
```

I am having one jQuery onload function in MainView

```
$(function(){
    if(typeof LoadLocationData == 'function'){ LoadLocationData(); }
    else if(typeof LoadUserData == 'function'){ LoadUserData(); }
});
```

At very first time after choosing SubView1, It executes the script function

```
LoadLocationData()
```

Then when I am choosing SubView2, It executes the script function

```
LoadLocationData()
```

In the above case it is expected to execute the script function

```
LoadUserData()
```

Can any one tell me where I am making mistake and what I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Where is your ajax? And specifically what is the problem you are having?

Comment: Ajax call is done when the user selects dropdown. And based on the loaded partial view, script should be executed.